# How to create a grid overlay for my tiles (Unity's Tilemaps)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, tile

I am using Unity's 2D Tilemaps.

Is there a way to draw a border around all the tiles in a Tilemap? (I want this to be an option in my game, thus it should be by code and should be "activable").

Here's a image example:
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Any chance you can post a picture showing what you’re talking about?

Comment: @CareyOn Done. I hope it helps ^^

Comment: So you want a grid overlay on your tiles?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm still not sure if it's possible to do it without editing the sprites themselves.

Comment: I don’t know how to do it in code, but it wouldn’t be that hard to create it in Photoshop and then enable and disable the gameObject that contains the grid sprite. Btw, maybe you should rename your post to ‘How to create a grid overlay for my tiles?’ It’ll make it that much clearer what you’re looking for.